# System Access in Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012

I've setup an Active Domain machine and a client machine, both with Windows Server installed. I have created a user account on the active domain but when I try to login to the client machine using the credentials I get the error message: "The credentials are correct, but you do not have permissions to access this system" How do I setup the necessary permissions?

Comment: More information will be needed. Do you mean you have a Windows server acting as an AD Domain Controller or????

Comment: Perhaps you set up an Active *Directory* domain controller, and you are trying to access it with RDP from a normal user account?  Maybe the second server is domain joined and you are trying to log in locally?  Is the second server also a DC?  What does it do?  This is unclear.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're trying to access the client machine with Remote Desktop and the user account you're authenticating with isn't a member of the "Remote Desktop Users" group on that client computer.

Make them a member of "Remote Desktop Users" in that client computer's "Local Users and Groups" and give it another go.